# Copy-Item fails when used in script with -FromSession between Hyper-V host and guest

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, powershell-remoting

> Host: Windows Server 2016
>
> Guest: Windows 10 x64 1903
>
> VM version: 8.0

First off, this VM lives in a different VLAN than the host and the NIC dedicated to that VLAN is not shareable with the host. Also, a 2nd, host-only network between the guest and the host is not an acceptable solution.

If I use `Copy-Item -FromSession` in an interactive session for every file, the file copy occurs without issue. However, when I attempt to use it in a script, I receive an error stating that the path for the source file does not exist, which makes sense because the path is supposed to be on the guest, not the host. I had the same problem when trying to use the `Get-ChildItem` because the operation was being executed in the context of the Hyper-V host, not the guest. However if I try to wrap the `Copy-Item -FromSession` in a `Invoke-Command` and inserting the `$Using:<var>` syntax, I receive an error stating that a parameter cannot be found

```
$VMRootDir = "Z:\vmshare\Completed\"     <# On the guest #>
$DestDir = "D:\Encoding Work\VMshare\"   <# Local to the host #>

# Setup Remote Session
$User = ".\psdirect"
$Pword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "********" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $Pword
$VMName = "TranscodeBox"
$S = New-PSSession -Credential $Cred -VMName $VMName
Enter-PSSession -Session $S

# Get Files to Copy
$files = Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem $Using:VMRootDir -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName } } 


# Copy Each File
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Get the new name
    $DestFileStr = $DestDir + $file.ToString().TrimStart($VMRootDir)

    #tell 'em what's happening
    write-host $file " -> " $DestFileStr


    #Do the copying
    <# This is were the error occurs #>
    Copy-Item -FromSession $S -Path $file -Destination $DestFileStr -Force
    Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item -FromSession $Using:S -Path $Using:file -Destination $Using:DestFileStr -Force}

    # Cleanup if the new file exists
    If (Test-Path $DestFileStr) {
        #Remove-Item $file
        Write-Host "Success  " $DestFileStr
    }
}

#Cleanup the Session
Exit-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -Session $S
```

Error Messages (repeated for every file):

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'Z:\vmshare\Completed\***\*****.mkv' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\******\Desktop\cpTranscodeBox.ps1:23 char:5
+     Copy-Item -FromSession $S -Path $file -Destination $DestFileStr - ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Z:\vmshare\Comp... *****.mkv:String) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
 
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FromSession'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : TranscodeBox
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the issue was caused by having `[` and `]` in the source file name, I resolved the issue by escaping the source file name wherever it existed

`[Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($<var>)`

Complete Script:

```
$VMRootDir = "Z:\vmshare\Completed\"    <# On the guest #>
$DestDir = "D:\Encoding Work\VMshare\"  <# Local to the host #>

# Setup Remote Session
$User = ".\psdirect"
$Pword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "********" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $Pword
$VMName = "TranscodeBox"
$S = New-PSSession -Credential $Cred -VMName $VMName
Enter-PSSession -Session $S

# Get Files to Copy
$files = Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem $Using:VMRootDir -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName } } 


# Copy Each File
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Get the new name
    $DestFileStr = $DestDir + $file.TrimStart($VMRootDir)

    #tell 'em what's happening
    write-host $file " -> " $DestFileStr

    #Create the Directory if it doesn't exist
    $newDir = ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($DestFileStr))
    if (!(Test-Path([Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($newDir)))) { mkdir $newDir }

    #Do the copying
    Copy-Item -FromSession $S -Path ([Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($file)) -Destination $DestFileStr 

    # Cleanup if the new file exists
        If (Test-Path ([Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($DestFileStr))) {
        invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock {Remove-Item ([Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($Using:file))}
        Write-Host "Success  " $DestFileStr
    }  
}

#Cleanup the Session
Exit-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -Session $S
```